# MS SQL delete specific value where are condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have three tables. The third one I am inserting changes which are created between tables 1 and 2

My problem is I can not fix the delete statement where I try to delete from column1 'Dog'. Table three should only contain changes to the values over the course of the day.

```
Table1 ---Yesterday
Column1 Column2    Column3 Column4
Dog       Blue      555      poo
Dog       Brown     666      hoo
Dog       Black     666      hoo
Mouse     Red       888      nic
Cat       Ping      444      pic

Table2 ---Today
Column1 Column2    Column3 Column4
Dog       Colour     555       poo ---Change column2
Dog       Brown      888       hoo ---Change column3
Dog       Black      666       hoo --- No change
Mouse     Red        888       nicoo ---Change column4
Cat       Ping       444       pic --- No change


Table3 ---Changes between days
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
Dog       Colour     555       poo ---Change column2
Dog       Brown      888       hoo ---Change column3
Dog       Black      666       hoo --- No change
Mouse     Red        888       nicoo ---Change column4

Table3 ---Expect Output
Mouse     Red        888       nicoo ---Change column4
Dog       Colour     555       poo ---Change column2
Dog       Brown      888       hoo ---Change column3


SELECT       *
FROM         [dbo].[Table3]
WHERE   Column1 = 'Dog' and    (  EXISTS
                             (SELECT     * 
                               FROM       [dbo].[Table2]  
                               WHERE        ([Table2].Column1 = Column1) AND ([Table2].Column1 = Column1
                                and 

    [Table3].[Column1] <> [Table1].[Column1] or
    [Table3].[Column2] <> [Table1].[Column2] or
    [Table3].Column3 <> [Table1].Column3 or 
    [Table3].Column4 <> [Table1].Column4 or 
    )))
```

Thanks for helping to find a solution for my delete statement!

Comment: First of all: if Table 3 stores your changes between Table 1 and Table 2 - how is it possible that it contains records without changes??

Comment: Different tables for different days... Horrible database design. Have one table, with a date column.

Comment: jarlh@ I add timestamp but i need actual data + history data in one table..

Comment: Can you specify how are you populating [Table3]?

Comment: Tyron78 @ column 1 is PK

Comment: Column 1 can't be a PK as it contains non unique values.

Comment: Sergio Prats @insert into [dbo].[Table3]
  select *
  from [dbo].[table2] t
  where exists
  (
    select *
    from [dbo].[table1] y
    where y.[column1] = t.[column1]
    and 
 (
 y.[column1] <> t.[column1]  or
    y.[column2] <> t.[column2] or
 y.column3 <> t.column3 or 
 y.column4 <> t.column4 
  ))

Comment: I'd suggest using EXCEPT operator. Have a look at here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188055%28v=sql.120%29.aspx

Comment: Dmitry Grekov @ it is table have 100k rows.. but some of them is dog only..

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by right join -

```
create table #Table1 (Column1 varchar(10) ,Column2 varchar(10)    ,Column3 int,Column4 varchar(10))
insert into #Table1
select 'Dog'       ,'Blue',      555      ,'poo'
union all select 'Dog'       ,'Brown',     666      ,'hoo'
union all select 'Dog'       ,'Black',     666      ,'hoo'
union all select 'Mouse'     ,'Red',       888      ,'nic'
union all select 'Cat'       ,'Ping',      444      ,'pic'

create table #Table2 (Column1 varchar(10) ,Column2 varchar(10)    ,Column3 int,Column4 varchar(10))
insert into #Table2
select 'Dog',       'Colour',     555       ,'poo'
union all select 'Dog',       'Brown',      888       ,'hoo' 
union all select 'Dog',       'Black',      666       ,'hoo' 
union all select 'Mouse',     'Red',        888       ,'nicoo' 
union all select 'Cat',       'Ping',       444       ,'pic' 

select t2.*
from #Table1 t1
right join #Table2 t2
on t1.Column1 = t2.Column1
and t1.Column2 = t2.Column2
and t1.Column3 = t2.Column3
and t1.Column4 = t2.Column4
where t1.Column1 is null  

--OUTPUT
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
Dog     Colour  555     poo
Dog     Brown   888     hoo
Mouse   Red     888     nicoo
```